# Edit aspx page cause session lost

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, visual-studio-2012

I am developing with VS2012 also it was same with VS2010. I working on a Web Application project.  I have added a virtual application on IIS and set my project root folder as `localhost/MyWebApp`.

It often happens, when I do a simple page edit (on .aspx files) my site loses sessions. I am sure that no server side code is changed or no `runat=server` tag was affected.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: A page edit causes the web application to re-start in IIS.  You may want to consider moving your session state to a SQL server or something outside of the IIS process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elaborating on David's comment:

> **File Change Notification**
>
> ASP.NET 2.0 depends on File Change Notifications (FCN) to see if the
>   application has been updated, and depending on the magnitude of change
>   the application pool will recycle. If you or your application are
>   adding and removing directories to the application folder, then you
>   will be restarting your application pool every time.
>
> Altering the following files also causes an immediate restart of the
>   application pool:
>
> ```
> web.config
> machine.config
> global.asax
> Any file in the /bin directory or subfolders
> ```
>
> Updating .aspx files, etc. causing a recompile eventually triggers a
>   restart of the application pool also. There is a property of the
>   compilation element under system.web called
>   numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart. The default value is 20, meaning that
>   after 20 recompiles the application pool will recycle.

Taken from: [Losing ASP.NET Sessions - Why Application Pools recycle](http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/losing-aspnet-sessions-why-application.html)

Comment: Thanks.. I also found [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319947](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319947) and gives config like that                <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"   numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="50" />

Answer (score 3):

Answer from Hans V:

> When using the default SessionState Mode "InProc", you session will
> be lost  when the application pool recycles. Therer are many reasons
> why this could happen,  but also when you change aspx files:
>
> ASP.NET depends on File Change Notifications (FCN) to see if the
> application has  been updated. Depending on the change the application
> pool will recycle. If you  or your application is adding and removing
> directories to the application folder,  you will be restarting your
> application pool every time, so be careful with those  temporary
> files.   Altering the following files will also trigger an immediate
> restart of the  application pool:
>
> - web.config
> - machine.config
> - global.asax
> - Anything in the bin directory or it's sub-directories
>
> Updating the .aspx files, etc. causing a recompile will eventually
> trigger a restart  of the application pool as well. There is a
> property of the compilation element under  system.web that is called
> numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart. The default value is 20. This  means
> that after 20 recompiles the application pool will recycle.

[Answer reference](http://forums.asp.net/t/1806022.aspx/1?Session%20resets%20on%20ASPX%20and%20CSS%20file%20changes%20with%20WebForms)